# Print html code in text area

Tags: html

Here I need to display text with break line but I simply display the html code inside the text area.
Here is my code

```
<?php
$msg.="From :";
$msg.="<br/>";
$msg.="To :";
$msg.="Date :";
print_r($msg);
?>
<textarea><?php print_r($msg);?></textarea>
```

I need to print html executed code in text area.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: use `echo`: `echo $msg`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML way to fix it, use ASCII characters `&#013; &#010;`.

> #### Carriage return `&#013;`
>
> #### Line feed `&#010;` (HTML entity: `&NewLine;`)
>
> REF: http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/carriage-return-ascii-code-13.html

```html
<textarea cols='60' rows='8'>This is line1&#13;&#10;This is line2</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your code from:

```
<textarea><?php print_r($msg);?></textarea>
```

to:

```
<textarea><?php echo $msg;?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
echo '<textarea>'.print_r($msg).'</textarea>';
```